# If the round brackets is correct and full in the entire string,

Tags: python

I asked to write `function` that get `string` and return `True` if the round brackets is correct and full in the entire string.
for example: string: (()) return `True`, but for the string (()( return `False`.

I started to write but I don't know how to check the second example.
Thank you.

```
def function(A):
    left=0
    right=0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i]== '(':
            left+=1
        if A[i]== ')':
            right+=1
    return left==right
```

Comment: The second example will return False as expected (at least if you use "len" instead of "length").

Comment: `length` is not a builtin function in python. Do you mean `len`?

Comment: You can also check the counts as you go and make sure `right` is never greater than `left`. That will catch out strings like `)(`.

Comment: for Jab  yes I mean len

Comment: @khelwood  but in the string there is also letters between the round brackets, so I can't write )(

Comment: @Shakedlevi I don't see your point.

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty much done the job in your function.

However, if you want to be aware which of them is more common on your string, you can handle with **else**

```py
def some_func(A):
    left=0
    right=0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i]== '(':
            left+=1
        if A[i]== ')':
            right+=1

    if left == right:
        return left == right # Obviously will return true
    else:
        return {'left': left, 'right' : right}

foo = some_func('((()')
print(foo)
```

**OUTPUT:**
{'left': 3, 'right': 1}

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(A):
    left=0
    right=0

    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i]== '(':
            left+=1
        if A[i]== ')':
            right+=1
        if left<right:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take a counter, and if the counter never goes under `0` and the final value is `0`, then this is `True`, otherwise this is `False`.

```
def correct_braces(string):
    counter = 0
    for s in string:
        if s == '(':
            counter += 1
        if s == ')':
            counter -= 1
        if counter < 0: # ')(' will fall in this case
            return False
    return counter == 0
```